# JAXB Marshal for HashSet, Map, and Lists

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I'm trying to convert a Java bean into an xml document and I'm having trouble with some of these more complex interfaces. Here is the setup:

```
protected Set<Object> field1;
protected Map<Integer, List<Object>> field2;
protected List<String> field3;
protected List<Object> field4;
protected List<Object> field5;
protected List<Object> field6;
protected List<String> field7;
protected List<Object> field8;
```

In each Object (which is itself a bean) I have the following at the top of each class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "field1",
    "field2",
    "field3",
    "field4",
    "field5",
    "field6",
    "field7",
    "field8"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
```

I keep getting an exception for the Map of Integers and Lists when I marshal the whole bean. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: you need to clarify the question more to show exactly what exception are you getting?secondly where is the code for transforming/marshalling the objects?have you seen http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/06/how-to-converts-java-object-to-xml-jaxb.html

Comment: also see https://www.tylerburton.ca/2012/03/a-quick-and-dirty-way-to-convert-java-objects-to-and-from-xml/

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have below three class

Customer class

```
package comparison;     
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Customer {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private List<phonenumber> phoneNumbers;

    public Customer() {
        phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();
    } 
}
```

Address class

```
package comparison;

public class Address {

    private String city;
    private String street;

}
```

and PhoneNumber class

```
package comparison;

public class PhoneNumber {

    private String type;
    private String number;

}
```

Now adding some dummy data

```
package comparison;

public class Data {

public static Customer CUSTOMER;

static {
    CUSTOMER = new Customer();
    CUSTOMER.setId(123);
    CUSTOMER.setName("Jane Doe");

    Address address = new Address();
    address.setStreet("1 A Street");
    address.setCity("Any Town");
    CUSTOMER.setAddress(address);

    PhoneNumber workPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
    workPhoneNumber.setType("work");
    workPhoneNumber.setNumber("555-WORK");
    CUSTOMER.getPhoneNumbers().add(workPhoneNumber);

    PhoneNumber cellPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
    cellPhoneNumber.setType("cell");
    cellPhoneNumber.setNumber("555-CELL");
    CUSTOMER.getPhoneNumbers().add(cellPhoneNumber);
} 
}
```

So now you apply marshalling to convert the object to xml

```
package comparison.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import comparison.Customer;

import static comparison.Data.CUSTOMER;

public class JAXBDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        JAXBElement<Customer> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<Customer>(new QName("customer"), Customer.class, CUSTOMER);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
    }
}
```

1. A JAXBContext needs to be initialized on the binding metadata before
   the marshal operation can occur.
2. Unlike XStream JAXB does not format
   the XML by default, so we will enable this feature.
3. With no metadata
   specified we need to supply JAXB with a root element name (and
   namespace).

The code will produce result:

```
<customer>
<id>123</id>
<address>
    <city>Any Town</city>
    <street>1 A Street</street>
</address>
<name>Jane Doe</name>
<phoneNumbers>
    <number>555-WORK</number>
    <type>work</type>
</phoneNumbers>
<phoneNumbers>
    <number>555-CELL</number>
    <type>cell</type>
</phoneNumbers>
```

By default JAXB will access public fields and properties.  You can configure JAXB to use field access with the following package level annotation.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
package comparison;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
```

You can look at this [blogpost](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html) for details.